# Standing up at 10% of the speed of light

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, speed-of-light

Suppose I have a frictionless swing that is released from a height H m and I stand up after it has passed below the pivot at a height h m. If I stand up very quickly, say at 10% of the speed of light, then is angular momentum conserved?

I would have to apply a very large force to accelerate to 10% of the speed of light, however, the time to reach to stand up my height (let say 1m) would be very small so the angular impulse would be infinitesimal.

Many thanks!

Comment: If there is a “below the pivot,” then rotational symmetry is broken and angular momentum is not conserved. Consider that a traditional swing in a gravitational field goes back and forth: its angular momentum changes sign. But assuming you rephrase around this broken symmetry: why would you expect relativistic motion *not* to conserve angular momentum?

Comment: You might be interested to study the [relativistic wheel](https://www.spacetimetravel.org/rad/rad.html), which has a complicated appearance because each piece of it undergoes a slightly different Terrell rotation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and that link - it looks interesting! Sorry I don't understand what you mean that rotational symmetry is broken. I thought that if you stand up under the pivot then since the force exerted on the string in parallel to the pivot then the torque is zero. But I guess since the changes occur over such a small time then angular impulse from gravity would be very small so angular momentum is conserved.

Comment: Your argument about perpendicular force and zero torque also applies in the nonrelativistic limit. It is related to the Coriolis effect.

Comment: Ok thank you! I have not really done relativistic mechanics yet, but its on the bucket list!